# How I can do Auto Landscape Fast Report VCL when Manual Build?

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I generate runtime report with Fast Reports and I need change page orientation when

```
FastReport.Engine.PageWidth>MyPage.PaperWidth
```

in ManualBuild.

I set `MyPage.Orientation:=poLandscape` but report is landscape and preview and print physical page is portrait.

My new idea:

```
procedure TBaseReporter.PrepareReport(pClearLastReport: boolean);
begin
  GenerateReport;
  FastRep.PrepareReport(pClearLastReport);
  if NeedLandscape then
  begin
    GenerateReport;
    GetReportPage(cPage).Orientation:=poLandscape;  //change main report page orientation
    FastRep.PrepareReport(pClearLastReport);
  end;
end;
```

How can I implement function NeedLandScape?

Comment: No, you can set page's orietation before page's preparing. TfrxReportPage.OnBeforePrint will not works too

Comment: I edited code but I need method how detect if needed switch to landscape.`FastReport.Engine.PageWidth>MyPage.PaperWidth` is allways True.

Comment: Try FastReport.Engine.PageWidth > MyPage.PaperWidth * fr01cm

Comment: I tryed this,but is allways true.

Comment: FastReport.Engine.PageWidth>MyPage.PaperWidth will not work. You should use another condition. Check ReportObject.Left + ReportObjectWidth > MyPage.PaperWidth

Comment: What do you mean ReportObject?My TfrxReport?

Comment: TfrxView (TfrxMemoView for example)